# Issues with django-allauth 0.34.0 with django 2.0, how do i update my package

Tags: django, django-allauth

i have problems using django-allauth in my project, like viewing/editing the socialaccount.

im getting

```
AttributeError at /en/admin/socialaccount/socialaccount/2/change/
'JSONField' object has no attribute '_get_val_from_obj'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/en/admin/socialaccount/socialaccount/2/change/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'JSONField' object has no attribute '_get_val_from_obj'
```

i tried getting the latest version but still get 0.34.0
    pip install django-allauth --upgrade

i've reviewed the github code and it looks like it's already fixed.
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/1878

noob question: how do i fix this? or do i need to wait for someone to update the installer?

The latest version in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-allauth
is version 0.34.0 - last updated - Oct 29, 2017

Comment: i just want to use their latest github code in my project but im not sure how to apply that to my other servers. advice pls?

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you would do it like this, specifing the hash of the exact commit you want:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth.git@cedad9f156a8c78bfbe43a0b3a723c1a0b840dbd#egg=django-allauth --upgrade
```

If you use a requirement file, you would specify it like this:

```
-e git+git://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth.git@cedad9f156a8c78bfbe43a0b3a723c1a0b840dbd#egg=django-allauth
```